# three.js multiple materials for line

Tags: three.js

Is there any way to use more than one material for Line geometry, in similar fasion it's used for Faces?

Basically what I need is a grid with dashed lines, and every 4-th line should be solid.

Comment: With three.js r.72 and `BufferGeometry.addGroup()`, you can do it. But it is just as easy to render two separate lines using `THREE.LineSegments()`.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I can see though, LineSegments is just what used to be Line with THREE.LinePieces mode, so it doesn't support multiple materials.

Comment: Correct. Like I said, render one `LineSegments` with dashed material, and another with solid material.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Was planning to implement it like Wireframe Helper, but I guess I'll have to implement it differently now.